# concurrency with h2 database

Tags: java, database, concurrency, h2

I have a table xxx  with id (id_xxx int AUTO_INCREMENT ) and name (name_xxx varchar (50)),
When I insert a new row in the table I made​​:

```
INSERT INTO xxx VALUES ​​("name for test");
```

and the result (int=1) of insertion is returned, then I display in my java interface a message "succseed!", until now it's a very basic and simple operation...
BUT,
when I want to return the inserted id_xxx,I have to do another query to the database:

```
INSERT INTO xxx VALUES ​​("name for test");
//after the insert response I made:
SELECT MAX (id_xxx) FROM xxx;
```

and I display in my java interface "succseed $$$ is your id_xxx  "....

the second version can easily cause a serious error during concurrent access to multiple users:
imagine a case when a user1 makes an insert... and then H2DB interrupt operations of this user then executes the insert of user2.
when user1 executes a select max (id_xxx) the H2DB return A FALSE id_xxx...

(I hope that my example is clear otherwise I will schematize this problem).

how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to retrieve keys generated by `insert` query, see [5.1.4 Retrieving Automatically Generated Keys](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/statement.html#1000569).